# Importing multiple excel files into one df in R whilst adding a new column to each individual file at the same time

Tags: r, import, data-manipulation

I am uploading multiple excel files into R as a df (one of multiple sheets in every file, all have the same format). I need to add an additional column while uploading the files to be displayed in the data frame. I have a column named 'feedback' in my original data. I need to add a column that shifts values in 'feedback' down by one (creating NA) in the first row of every sheet (i.e. subject) that is being uploaded.

My code for importing the data into R looks like this:

```
files <- dir(
  path = "my path",
  pattern = ".xlsx",
  full.names = TRUE)


# Store the names of the sheets to be accessed, using one of the files
# as the template for the sheet names
all_sheets <- excel_sheets(files[1])

# .x is the vector of the file paths. map_df gives a single data frame/tibble as its output
# "for each file path..."

merged_files <- files %>% map_dfr(read_xlsx, .id = "sbj_no", sheet = all_sheets[2]) %>%
  select(response, time, feedback, target, sbj_no)
```

I cannot figure out how to add/create the required column in the process of importing the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to combine all sheets from each workbook into one and create a column for the name of the workbook and a column for the name of the sheet:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readxl)

files <- list.files(path="C:\\",pattern='*.xlsx')
wbs <- paste("C:\\", files, sep="\\")

read_multiple_excel <- function(path) {
    path %>%
    excel_sheets() %>% 
    set_names() %>% 
    map_df(~read_excel(path=path, sheet = .x, ..., .id = "sheet")
}

data_df <- wbs %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map_df(read_multiple_excel, .id = "wb")
```

Comment: Thank you! Managed to make it work :)